# Xamarin project doesn't build in MSBuild unless "pre-built" in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project that throws "This package is unresolved" errors for all dependencies when attempting to build with MSBuild. Interestingly, if I try building it in Xamarin first and then try re-running the build in MSBuild, it works.

This is the shell script that starts the build:

```
mono .paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe
mono .paket/paket.exe restore
mono packages/FAKE/tools/FAKE.exe $1 --fsiargs -d:MONO -d:$DEFINE build.fsx
```

This is the relevant part of my build.fsx:

```
let MSbuildConfigQA   = [ "Configuration", "Release"; "Platform", "Any CPU"; "Environment", "QA"]

Target "Build-Droid-QA" (fun _ ->
    UpdateAndroidManifest QA version buildNumber (droidFolder) 
    !! droidProject
        |> MSBuild (buildDir </> "project.Droid/QA") "Build" MSbuildConfigQA 
        |> Log "----Android build output----"
)
```

These are the errors I get initially when building through MSBuild:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Newtonsoft.Json' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'HockeySDK.AndroidBindings' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'HockeySDK' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' not resolved
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' not resolved
```

After getting these errors, I open the project in Xamarin and try building from there. The build completes successfully without any errors. I then try re-running MSBuild via my build script, and now the project successfully builds even though it was not before.

Comment: Do a `nuget restore` before building

Comment: @SushiHangover This works. I thought the `paket restore` in my build script was handling this, but that command uses the dependencies in the `paket.lock` file but mine was empty for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Are all your packages located in a `paket.lock` file? I'm assuming your project's nugets are located in a `package.config`....

Comment: I see you figured it out...

Comment: @SushiHangover I have `package.config` files (one for Android, one for iOS, etc) but the `paket.dependencies` was empty. I filled it in which got rid of the `cannot be resolved` errors, but I'm getting errors saying `No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light`. But when I do a `nuget restore` prior to building, it doesn't throw this error so something is still off with my paket config it seems